# Empty coverage file with flutter test --coverage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

When running one of the following commands (with or without output path) the generated .info file is completely empty:

```
flutter test --no-pub --machine --coverage

flutter test --no-pub --machine --coverage --coverage-path coverage/lcov_test_app_flutter.info
```

This seemed to be an issue already 3 years ago: [Issue #322](https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/322)

I also found a comment in that issue with the following message:

> Hello from (almost) April 2023: Issue re-appeared. coverage is empty
> with latest stable.

Test looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Test', () {
    expect(1, 1);
  });
}
```

Is there any solution for now?

PS: Tried with versions `3.13.0`, `3.10.6`, `3.10.0`

Comment: Shouldn't your test be calling some of your code that you are trying to test?